Why doesn't `char` lose data when an `int` is being assigned to it?
I'm a novice C programmer. I defined two variables int x = 0xffffffff and char y = x, thereafter I printed that using the printf("%x\n", y) function; I was expecting something like ff on the terminal, instead it printed ffffffff onto the screen. I'm wondering how can a char store 4 bytes of storage, when the storage size of a char is 1.
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 0xffffffff;
    char y = x;
    printf("%x\n", y);

    return 0;
}


If you pass a variable of smaller size than int to a variadic function like printf it is automatically promoted to int. The function doesn't even know that you passed a char.

It's because %x is for printing ints. So it takes your char which is signed in your case and negative and sign-extending it into an int of the same value (-1).

Putting it simpler, 0xffffffff is a representation of the value -1 for the int type. For the char type -1 is represented by 0xff. In both types -1 is representable, so no data is lost when assigning it back and forth. The loss will happen if the value is not representable in one of the types (think out of the type's range).

use that printf("%hhx\n", y);

@emre it works! BTW, what does %hhx format specifier stands for? Thanks for your suggestion.

The h in %hx stands for short or half unsigned int. repeated as %hhx means even shorter, hence unsigned char.  The value is converted internally by printf to respectively (unsigned short) or (unsigned char) before the string conversion. Note however that the C Standard supports architectures where 2 or even all 3 types char, short and int have the same size.

... and even then, the char value is still promoted to int when passed. Even when the format is %c, which means that you can pass int to %c.

If you change the line int x = 0xffffffff; to int x = 0xeeeeeeee;, then you will see that data is indeed being lost. See this link for a demonstration.

There's actually a fair amount of thing going on here.  First:
int x = 0xffffffff;

The integer constant 0xffffffff has a value of 4,294,967,295 (i.e. 232-1) and a type of unsigned int, assuming an int is 32 bit.
This unsigned int value is then converted to int for the initialization.  This undergoes an implementation-defined conversion, which in most cases results in the value -1 being assigned.  This value happens to have the same representation as the original value in two's complement.
Then on this line:
char y = x;

We're initializing y with the value -1.  This value is in the range of a char (assuming char is signed) so there is no change in value when converting from int to char in this case.  Assuming two's complement representation, this is represented as 0xff.
Then when you print:
printf("%x\n", y);

Because printf is a variadic function, the argument y which has type char is promoted to type int before being passed to the function.  As before, both types can store the value -1 so the value is unchanged.
The %x format specifier expects an argument of type unsigned int.  Since an int was passed instead of an unsigned int this is technically undefined behavior, however it's unlikely a signed/unsigned mismatch would cause an issue on any real implementation.
That being the case, the int value of -1 has a representation of 0xffffffff which when interpreted as an unsigned int would have that value, so ffffffff is what is printed.
So to answer your question:

how can a char store 4 bytes of storage, when the storage size of a char is 1.

It doesn't.  It just appears that way due to conversions and representations of the relevant types.

Assuming two's complement representation, this is represented as 0xff.  I'm afraid this part is still a bit confusing: if char is signed, the value is -1, which, in systems using two's complement representation, is stored in a byte with all bits set.  The debugger would show a byte value of FF but printf will output ffffffff because of the integer promotion rule as explained.
